# Function does not have my method available

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have been racking my brain on this one for hours now and I have looked at probably 30  online tutorials by now. As far as I can tell, I am not doing anything wrong, but yet I am having problems. I have some test code:

```
TestPulse = function() {};
TestPulse.prototype.go = function() { alert('You just pulsed'); };
TestPulse.go();
```

I also tried:

```
function TestPulse() {};
TestPulse.prototype.go = function() { alert('You just pulsed'); };
TestPulse.go();
```

Finally fed up, I just ripped some code from a few prototyping and namespace tutorials around the web, and no matter what I do, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function TestPulse(){} has no method 'go'

Like I said, I am not sure I am doing anything wrong...so what exactly is going on here?  When I debug, I do see a prototype object attached to the function, with the constructor and all, so I know its there. Where is the issue? Am I not understanding how prototyping works?

Comment: Please give a more descriptive title to your question, for the benefit of others.

Comment: If you want `TestPulse.go` to work, you have to assign the method like `TestPulse.go = function() { ... }` as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for everyone's quick answers, we just decided to move to prototype notation for stuff and it is just confusing sometimes. Now I know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have an instance of TestPulse...

```
TestPulse = function() {};
TestPulse.prototype.go = function() { alert('You just pulsed'); };
new TestPulse().go();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HYWPk/

Answer (score 5):

You need to create an instance of your TestPulse object to access the prototype methods on it.

```
TestPulse = function() {};
TestPulse.prototype.go = function() { alert('You just pulsed'); };
var testPulse = new TestPulse();
testPulse.go();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/H2dnv/

Comment: Son of a...So prototypes only add instance properties and methods?

Comment: You can still invoke the method directly through the prototype.

Comment: Yeah. When you were calling `TestPulse.go()` it is looking for the function `go` on the prototype of Object.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var a = new TestPulse;
a.go();
```

or

```
TestPulse.prototype.go();
```

Answer (score 1):

TestPulse is your (let's say) class. You need to create an instance from it.

```
var myObject = new TestPulse();
myObject.go();
```

That should work.